# Search URL with query parameter

Tags: reactjs, next.js, url-routing, router

When I want to search for a product and upon search button click it should be routed to the "/search?q=xxxx" page. I'm using React Nextjs 13 and my folder structure is like:

- app -->

  - components -->

    - SearchBar.tsx
  - search -->

    - layout.tsx
    - page.tsx

Here is my SearchBar component code:

```js
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TbSearch } from "react-icons/tb";
import { SearchBarProps } from "../../globals/types";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const SearchBar: React.FC<SearchBarProps> = (props) => {
  const [SearchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSearch = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const encodedSearchQuery = encodeURI(SearchQuery);
    router.push(`/search?q=${encodedSearchQuery}`);
    console.log("current query ", encodedSearchQuery);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSearch} className="relative">
      <input
        value={SearchQuery}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
        placeholder={props.searchPlaceholder}
        type="text"
        className="bg-gray-100 border-0 rounded-full px-4 py-3 pl-5 w-full focus:outline-none"
      />
      <button type="submit">
        <TbSearch className="absolute right-5 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 text-xl text-primary font-bold hover:cursor-pointer" />
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

On my page.tsx I am using some mock data. My problem is that I'm getting `encodedSearchQuery` in my console but after adding `?q=` I can't get the query in url parameter that would be something like '/search?q=abc' and it remains as only '/search'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: react doesn't provide a method to get the query in isolation, so if you want to get the query in isolation, the only way to do that is to use an external module or extract it directly from the address.

Comment: yes, i'm already trying to extract it directly from the address. I still can't get the way i want my query that would be like ?q= .

Comment: I think we need to provide more information about the code that extracts the query from the address.

Comment: @AninditaRoy I think it is not safe to change route when input value is changed. You can type serveral charactors in a second and the route will be changed several times in a second.

Comment: @JasonMing , Then how should i implement this? please provide me some solution. It would be helpful

Comment: @AninditaRoy Where do you render SearchBar component? in search page?

Comment: @JasonMing No, Rendering product component on search page. Inside of this product component there are some other component , i'm rendering the SearchBar component in Navbar.tsx component. Basically the stucture is like: Navbar.tsx --> SearchBar.tsx and Search -- > page.tsx -- > product.tsx. So, the SearchBar component is not directly rendered in search page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume giving query params as a combined string is filtered by the router. Hope this is better:

```js
router.push(pathname, { query: { param: 'value' } });
```

You could join the multiple values as described in the `createQueryString` is shown below:

```js
  const createQueryString = useCallback(
    (name: string, value: string) => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams)
      params.set(name, value)
 
      return params.toString()
    },
    [searchParams]
  )

router.push(pathname + '?' + createQueryString('q', 'param1'))
```

On the destination page `useSearchParams` is the desired way to grab arguments.

The full example is [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#examples).

Comment: I can grab arguments by using useSearchParams. But it does not appear on url like the way i want. I am getting the search url as '/search' but i want it as 'search?q=abc'.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it in Nextjs 14 and it works fine. Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/fileread-3wxw3l?file=%2Fapp%2Fsearch%2Fpage.tsx%3A18%2C1). Perhaps you could try upgrading Nextjs version if that's the problem.